# apache reverse proxy changes url

Tags: apache, redirect, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf

i tried to configure apache's reverse proxy on a server to redirect the requests from /hotm to http://gateway.messenger.hotmail.com

typing the addres xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/hotm in a browser, the request is redirected correctly, but the url in the address bar changes to "http://gateway.messenger.hotmail.com".

it's possible to configure the proxy on apache so that the address does not change?

[edit]
this is the httpd.conf fragment

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /hotm http://gateway.messenger.hotmail.com
ProxyPassReverse /hotm http://gateway.messenger.hotmail.com
<Directory /var/www/html/hotm>
 Order Allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>
Redirect Permanent /hotm http://gateway.messenger.hotmail.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must also set the [`ProxyPassReverse`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) directive, typically to the same url as your [`ProxyPass`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) value.

Comment: i use the directive "ProxyPreserveHost On" and it works. thanks

Comment: I also use `ProxyPassReverse` and `ProxyPreserveHost On`, but then get a "too many redirect". Does nay one know how to resolve?