# Rewrite URL in Nginx proxy + apache setup

Tags: django, apache, nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I'm working in python/django with apache and a Nginx proxy.

I need to transform some URLs like these:

`www.mydomain.com/client_A/`

`www.mydomain.com/client_B/`

to

`www.mydomain.com/clients/1/`

`www.mydomain.com/clients/2/`

I would do a rewrite in the Nginx configuration, but the problem is that this should Not be visible to the user, rather he should keep seeing the URL as www.mydomain.com/client_A/ and Not as the internal URL.

The main idea is to do this in the `Nginx/Apache` configuration

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe

```
 rewrite ^/client_A/(.*)$ /clients/1/$1 last;
```

in nginx config should work.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the following post for related question.

[apache reverse proxy changes url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277107/apache-reverse-proxy-changes-url)

The idea is to use a `reverse proxy` with `Apache` to keep URLs same.