# Reverse proxy: unwanted URL change

Tags: apache, apache2, mod-proxy, http-proxy

I have a web-service that I would like to expose through the URL `foo.com/bar`.
However my Apache reverse proxy does not work as intended. 
I have created the file `001-default.conf`, which contains the following code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass /bar http://foo.com:8080/bar
    ProxyPassReverse /bar foo.com:8080/bar

    DocumentRoot /var/www/foo/
    ServerName info.foo.com
    <Directory /var/www/foo>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Right now I receive a `404` error code.

I want to achieve all hits on foo.com/bar to be silently redirected to `foo.com:8080/bar`, meaning that the user should only see the URL `foo.com/bar`. 
The reverse proxy redirect should also include requests such as `foo.com/bar?=foobar`.

I did enable proxy_http and proxy:

```
% sudo a2enmod proxy_http        
  Considering dependency proxy for proxy_http:
  Module proxy already enabled
  Module proxy_http already enabled
```

I hope that there is someone out there that are able to help me with this.

Similar problem that did not solve my problem:
    [apache reverse proxy changes url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277107/apache-reverse-proxy-changes-url) [Transparent redirect to port 8080](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801246/transparent-redirect-to-port-8080?rq=1)

Comment: For starters, remove: `Redirect Permanent /bar http://foo:8080/bar`. You want to proxy, not redirect. Your existing `ProxyPass` directives should do that.

Comment: Now I get a 404 when entering www.foo.com/bar. I have updated my question to reflect this change.

Comment: Your servername is info.foo.com, which means that foo.com might hit another VHOST.

Comment: Try and add http:// to the proxy pass reverse directive

Comment: What version of Apache are you using?

Comment: @Kabahango I removed the servername because I do not use it.
The http:// does nothing. I am using Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and edit the config to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Proxy *> 
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass /bar http://foo.com:8080  # Note removed /bar
    ProxyPassReverse /bar foo.com:8080  # Note removed /bar

    DocumentRoot /var/www/foo/
    ServerName info.foo.com
    <Directory /var/www/foo>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You can also try with mod_alias to avoid te /bar/bar issue you might be facing now. 
I do not know much about it, see the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html

Try something like adding this to your conf

```
 Alias /bar http://foo.com:8080
```

Using this you might wan't to remove the proxy.

Comment: This redirect the user to http://foo.com:8080 displaying the URL http://foo.com/bar, this is indeed progress but I still need to redirect to http://foo.com:8080/sparql. As fare as I can gather then Alias do not work when a port is involved. :S